# It's possible to add feature blending mode in Geoserver

Tags: qgis, geoserver, style, sld

I exported layer style from QGIS as SLD file to use it in Geoserver, but unfortunately feature blending mode did not applied on Geoserver, so it's possible to edit SLD style in Geoserver to add feature blending mode.

edit
style in qgis
[image: feature blending]

[image: feature blending qgis]

in Geoserver

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Roads 1style</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Roads 1style</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Freeway</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Freeway</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Freeway</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>300000</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>3000000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MainRoad</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MainRoad</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MainRoad</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>300000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MainStreet</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MainStreet</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MainStreet</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>100000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MinorStreet</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MinorStreet</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MinorStreet</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>40000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>CollectorStreet</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>CollectorStreet</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>CollectorStreet</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>40000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Tunnel</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Tunnel</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Tunnel</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>300000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">7</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">18 14</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#2d4cd9</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">18 14</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_en</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>Freeway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_en</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>MainRoad</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>300000</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>700000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>name_en</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Calibri</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">11</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:LinePlacement>
                <se:PerpendicularOffset>7</se:PerpendicularOffset>
                <se:GeneralizeLine>true</se:GeneralizeLine>
              </se:LinePlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="group">yes</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_en</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>Tunnel</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_en</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>MainStreet</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_en</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>MainStreet</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_en</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>CollectorStreet</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>30000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>name_en</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Calibri</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:LinePlacement>
                <se:PerpendicularOffset>7</se:PerpendicularOffset>
                <se:GeneralizeLine>true</se:GeneralizeLine>
              </se:LinePlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

[image: Geoserver style]
[image: Geoserver style2]

there is missing feature blending mode in geoserver style.

i tried to add the following parameter from geoserver doc, but unfortunatly it did not applied on sld dtyle

```html
<se:VendorOption name="color-blending">addition</se:VendorOption>
```

Comment: do you mean like https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/composite-blend/modes.html

Comment: i tried that, but unfortunately there is no any changes on layer style

Comment: Where did you see that line in the docs? it's not one of the options listed on https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/composite-blend/modes.html

Comment: i tried before add composite parameter <se:VendorOption name="composite">lighten</se:VendorOption>or any othe blending modes, after that i did not find any changes on layer style

Comment: i tried to change composite with color-blending to see if there any changes, just for testing